# Minimum conditions for human life

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, health, life, human

I don't know so much about biology, my strengths it is in physical science and mathematics.

Well i like rifle shooting, I don't hunt, i think that is cruelty and coward.

In some conditions of temp,humidity and pressure, you can do a great shot, but i think that the limits or conditions are wrong.

So i would like to know what conditions of humidity, pressure and temp at the same time, it is possible to be a live as human in a fixed position over the ground without moving or doing some excercise.

Looks like a cold weather, but you know better that than me.

Comment: No help? The blood freeze at -3 Celsius